# How to get min billed client and maximum billed client in a same query by joining a client table and an billing table

Tags: mysql

TABLE :  `client`

```
cliendid  clientname
1            John Doe
2            Funny Boy
3            Non Funny
```

Table : `Billing`

```
billid clientid  amount
1       3        100
2       3        100
3       1        50
4       2        800
5       1        30
```

Looking for a query that returns me

```
MinBillingAmount    MinBillingClient    MaxBillingAmount  MaxBillingClient
80                   John Doe             800              Funny Guy
```

Can't even start to figure where to start and if it is even possible.  Trying to figure it out who is the most profitable and who is the least profitable.

Comment: 50 +30   In billing table  sum of amount for clientid 1 who is John Doe